# Connect to browser with austin

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, clojurescript, ring

I followed along the following instructions for my own project: https://github.com/cemerick/austin/tree/master/browser-connected-repl-sample. I think things derailed at step 2:

> Once you're in the REPL (it will start up in the sample app's main
>   namespace, cemerick.austin.bcrepl-sample), evaluate (run). That just
>   starts jetty on port 8080; if you open a browser to that server,
>   you'll see this page (which the sample re-uses as its only content).

I've been starting my server with `$ lein ring server-headless` as opposed to starting in the REPL and I'm pretty sure that's what's causing `[:script (cemerick.austin.repls/browser-connected-repl-js)]` to not generate the proper javascript. In the browser, the source code shows `<script></script>` while it gets properly generated in the REPL.

How would I run the equivalent of `$ lein ring server-headless` from the REPL if this is indeed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with a similar situation a time ago.

Here I left the steps I followed to obtain this austin script:

1. Introduce in the project repl: `(def repl-env (reset! cemerick.austin.repls/browser-repl-env (cemerick.austin/repl-env)))`
2. adapt the result expression `Browser-REPL ready @ http://localhost:XXXXX/ZZZ/repl/start` to the js script: `<script>;goog.require('clojure.browser.repl');clojure.browser.repl.connect.call(null, 'http://localhost:XXXX/ZZZ/repl');</script>`. Note that only 'XXXX/ZZZ' changes each time
3. write into nrepl `(cemerick.austin.repls/cljs-repl repl-env)`
4. reload your browser

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I never got it working with `$ lein ring server-headless` since I switched to immutant before I found much need to figure this out.

Immutant creates a repl when it starts whose port can be specified in your project file. I use cider in emacs and connect to it with `M-x cider` and specify the port when prompted. From here just follow the tutorial steps. One thing that caught me and took a few minutes to figure out was that the script tag in your html with `browser-connected-repl-js` needs to be in the very end of your `<body>`; doesn't seem to work in `<head>`.

The key take-away for set-ups with similar issues is that you need to reset an atom and the javascript in your html code needs access to this atom. For the original problem with `$ lein ring server-headless`, you'll probably want to start the server in the repl and follow the tutorial.